# Android Studio - Activity's layout shows flipped (RTL instead of LTR)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have this issue in my App, which is super weird.

I have an app, when i press *Run* on Android Studio, it starts the app with the correct layout's direction. Now, i press Back button and go back to the app, it shows a RTL layout instead of the current, correct LTR layout.

The app is pretty simple, it has an Activity with a NavigationButton in the Toolbar, when its flipped, the NavigationButton goes from left to the right, with a false pointing direction.

The app is LTR, supports only English, and tested on an English device, the same result is happening on the Emulator. I have the final version of Android Studio.

- Layout, with Toolbar, along with navigation attribute, to enable back arrow.
- Activity which setContentView and just shows the layout.
- Back pressing, or re-opening the App without clearing it from the BackStack, shows the visual bug.

What cause the issue? as the code is pretty simple and doesn't have anything hardcore.

Manifest Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.corF.app">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.corF.app.activities.ActivityStartup"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Post some code. Manifest will be useful

Comment: Added the manifest code.

Comment: remove this line from manifest application tag  android:supportsRtl="true"

Comment: Still the same issue :/

Comment: Do you speak a language other than English? Is the device (android or development computer) set to a language other than English? What directory are the resources in? Android will use the language and regional dialect it thinks applies to the user of the app. What about string resource directory?

Comment: the device has "English" as default language, the same goes for the App. As I've stated in my answer, this Slider had RTL forcing code in its MainActivity class (SliderLayout.java As far as i remember).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A library which i use (SliderLayout), has a code which forces the app to show RTL. On the first launch the SliderLayout forces the RTL, but it doesn't take change until i re-open the app without fully removing it from the backstack.

Silly issue, but yeah, this's the solution.